# Panda Slicing Notation whats better

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Basically I want to know what the difference between:

```
data.iloc[0:2]
```

and

```
data[0:2]
```

Wouldn't both of these pandas dataframes. return the same information? Does it matter with one I use?

Comment: Read the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html) to know the difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They can be different when your DataFrame's indexes are different from the position.
`iloc` is based on the absolute position like a `list` in Python.
`loc` is based on the index of the DataFrame.

For example, if we have this DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['a'], ['b'], ['c'], ['d']], index=[1, 2, 3, 4])
df
```

```
    0
1   a
2   b
3   c
4   d
```

`iloc` will give you position-based slicing not the index of the `df`. Please note that it does not include the last positon.

```
data.iloc[1:3]
```

```
    0
2   b
3   c
```

On the contrary, `loc` will give you index-based slicing. Please note that this includes the last index of the given slice.

```
data.loc[1:3]
```

```
    0
1   a
2   b
3   c
```

For a more detail, please refer to [this page](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html).